# Subtotals with group by

Tags: views

I have a view which groups content by date and each row has a field with a numeric value (the worked field in the screenshot below). At the end of each group I would like to display the sum total of the 'Worked' field.

Is this possible in Views?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this module will help? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator